# / How can I print out all the even vectors different from 0

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Here is my code.How can I print out all the even vectors different from 0? The result is incorrect but I don't know what is the problem here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std ;
int main ()
{
    int i,j,N,M;
    int a[100][100];
    cout << "the number of rows of the matrix = " ;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "the number of columns of the matrix ";
    cin >> M;

    for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=M;j++)
        { 
            cin >> a[i][j]; 
        }
    }
    cout <<"even vectors different from 0 ";
    for (i=1; i<=N;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=M;j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j]!=0 && a[i][j]%2==0)
            {
                cout<<a[i][j];
            }   
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly indent the code. That will make it much easier to read and understand. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why is there a `return` statement inside your loop! The loop will exit after first iteration.

Comment: And while you're still a beginner, please learn away the 1-based array indexing. Array indexes are *zero* based, An array of `X` elements will have indexes in the range of `0` to `X - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `int a[100][100];` is very dangerous. If `M` or `N` is larger than `100` (or in your case, because you are using 1-based index, `99`), it will cause out-of-bounds, which leads to undefined behavior. You should use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Second, I format the code for you, and the problem becomes clear that `return 0;` is at the wrong place.

Overall, your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include <cmath> why?
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    int N{};
    int M{};
    std::cout << "the number of rows of the matrix = " ;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cout << "the number of columns of the matrix ";
    std::cin >> M;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(N, std::vector<int>(M));

    for (int i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < M; j++)
        { 
            std::cin >> a[i][j]; 
        }
    }
    std::cout <<"even vectors different from 0 ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < M; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] != 0 && a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                std::cout << a[i][j];
            }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` causes memory fragmentation, while `int a[100][100]` does not.

Comment: @Tobi That's often not an issue (if it is then use a vector of `N * M` elements instead). And it also makes it possible to use arbitrary sizes for the data.